# Python: save output file with the logged-in username appended to the file name

Tags: python, f-string, getpass

I have a python program that creates an output file. That all works correctly.
However, I'd now like to save the python output file with a "_username" appended to the filename.

I have included the following in my code:

```
import getpass

username = getpass.getuser()

output_excel_file = (r'C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Outputs\Outputs_{username}.xlsx')
```

This works except it saves the file as `Outputs_{username}.xlsx` instead of `Outputs_tomsmith.xlsx`

Why am i not getting the value of the variable in my path file name?

I've tried using getpass, but the variable doesn't seem to be populating with the value of the variable being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `f-string` to format it correctly.

```py
import getpass

username = getpass.getuser()

output_excel_file = rf"C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Outputs\\Outputs_{username}.xlsx"
```

or the `format` method

```
output_excel_file = 'C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Outputs\\Outputs_{}.xlsx'.format(username)
```